# Reverse game python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i know this is asked a couple of times already but i couldnt find the answer.
The question is about the reverse guess my number game.
The code executes the program but not in a "humanlike" way. If the number is 50 and it guesses 20 it responds as higher, the computer says 30 for example, it gets the response lower it guesses 15. How do i solve this?
The exercise comes from: Python for the absolute beginner.
Can someone help me? In a simple way please because otherwise i skip things in the book.
I think you can see what i know and what not by seeing the code.
Please help me...

Code:

```
#Guess My Number
#
#The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
#The playes tries to guess it and the coputer lets
#the player know if the guess is too high, too low
#or right on the money

print ("\t// // // // // // // // // //")
print ("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print ("\tComputer VS Human")
print ("\t// // // // // // // // // //")
name = input("What's your name?")
print ("Hello,", name)
print ("\nOkay, think of a number between 1 and 100.")
print ("I'll try to guess it within 10 attemps.")

import random

#set the initial values

the_number = int(input("Please type in the number to guess:"))
tries = 0
max_tries = 10
guess = random.randint(1, 100)

#guessing loop
while guess != the_number and tries < max_tries:
    print("Is it", guess,"?")
    tries += 1

    if guess > the_number and tries < max_tries:
        print ("It's lower")
        guess = random.randint(1, guess)
    elif guess < the_number and tries < max_tries:
        print ("It's higher")
        guess = random.randint(guess, 100)
    elif guess == the_number and tries < max_tries:
        print("Woohoo, you guessed it!")
        break
    else:
        print("HAHA you silly computer it was", the_number,"!")

input ("\n\nTo exit, press enter key.")
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep track of the highest possible value and the lowest possible value so you can guess intelligently.

Initially, the lowest possible value is 1 and the highest is 100.
Let's say you guess 50, and the computer responds "higher". What happens to your two variables? The lowest possible value now becomes 50, since the number cannot be lower than that. The highest value remains the same.

If the computer responds "lower", the opposite happens.

Then you will guess between the lowest and the highest possible values:

`random.randint(lowest, highest)`

And your guesses will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, but where in the code do i put that then?

Comment: Declare the two variables `lowest` and `highest` after the `import random`. In both the "lower" and "higher" if statements, you readjust the value of the variables. Any time you guess you will use `guess = random.randint(lowest, highest)`

Answer (score 2):

Reading up on [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Normally these games work by making the range of possible numbers SMALLER each time a new guess is made. i.e.

```
1st guess = 20
guess is too low 
--> range of guesses is now (21, 100)

2nd guess = 45
guess is too high
--> range of guesses is now (21, 44)
etc...
```

In your tests, you forget about all previous guesses, so it can't do this. You could try to keep track of the lower and higher ends of the range:

```
lower_range, higher_range = 1, 100
max_tries = 10

#guessing loop
while tries < max_tries:
    guess = random.randint(lower_range, higher_range)
    print("Is it", guess,"?")
    tries += 1

    if guess > the_number:    
        print ("It's lower")
        higher_range = guess - 1

    elif guess < the_number:
        print ("It's higher")
        lower_range = guess + 1

    else:    # i.e. correct guess
        print("Woohoo, you guessed it!")
        input ("\n\nTo exit, press enter key.")
        sys.exit(0)

print("HAHA you silly computer it was", the_number,"!")
```

Have also tidied up the while loop a little.

Often, these games take advantage of Binary Search methods as well. For fun, you could try to implement this :) Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanx nick. Your's didn't really work for me in idle (idle with python 3.1 on debian linux) But i added the higher_range = guess -1 an the lower_range to my code as it was and everything works as it should now. Thanx alot